# Is it possible to use react inside a firefox extension page-mod?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firefox-addon-sdk

I am trying to add a list of buttons (just a proof on concept) to a page using a firefox extension.

I was able to do so by using plain js, however i wonder if it would be possible to use react inside a content script to build the page modification.

I tried creating a standalone react app and then including the bundled files as a contentScriptFile.

```
pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "*",
  contentScriptFile: './bundle.js',
});
```

Which results in an error message after running `jpm run`:

```
Object
- _errorType = TypeError
- message = can't define property "Headers": Object is not extensible
- fileName = resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/loader/sandbox.js -> resource://newreactapp/data/bundle.js
- lineNumber = 5
```

Is there a fix to this problem? I wasn't able to find an example either.

Comment: FYI: If at all possible, you should be using [WebExtensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions) instead of the Add-on SDK. As of this point, only WebExtension based extensions are being accepted for review and listing on AMO (you can still provide updates to already listed extensions that are not based on WebExtensions). Support for non-WebExtensions based extensions will be removed from the release version of Firefox as of Firefox 57, scheduled for 2017-11-14.

Answer (score 1):

May be [this example](https://github.com/firebug/pixel-perfect/blob/master/data/popup.js) helps you.

There is also an example [here](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2017/06/network-monitor-reloaded/) which uses React/Redux stack.